# How to install PolyaGamma package in R?

Tags: r, installation, package

I am trying to install the following package from Github, First I have installed `devtools` as

```
install.packages("devtools")
```

And then I run the following line for `PolyaGamma` package

```
devtools::install_github("kasparmartens/PolyaGamma")
```

Unfortunately, got the following error

```
> devtools::install_github("kasparmartens/PolyaGamma")
Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'pkgload', details:
  call: loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]])
  error: namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.0 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.1 is required
```

How can I install `PolyaGamma`? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you need to update your rlang package version:

`install.packages('rlang')`

Comment: I am using 3.6.1 version.

Comment: yes so am i, but you have a package in your package listing called 'rlang' and mine is currently 0.4.2 and yours is 0.4.0 and needs to be greater than 0.4.1 per the error message to install the desired package.

Comment: I have installed `rlang` first and then tried `devtools` and `PolyaGamma` but still shows the same error.

Comment: you ran the command `install.packages('rlang')` in the command line?

Comment: This is what I am trying
`install.packages('rlang')`

`install.packages("devtools")` and 

`devtools::install_github("kasparmartens/PolyaGamma")`